# ggplot why 'show.legend = FALSE' not working?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have this piece of code in my shiny app,
Can somebody tell me why `show.legend = FALSE` not working ?
I would like to remove legend.

Here is my project http://webcovid19.online/
Legend not working  e.g. here http://webcovid19.online/?country=Slovakia

```
output$dead_inc_country_bar_plot <- renderPlotly({
     ggplotly(
       
       
       ggplot(filtered_dead_inc_country_bar_data(), aes(x = date, y = deaths, color = country,group = country, text=paste(date, "\n" , country, " " ,deaths  ))) +
         geom_bar(stat='identity',fill='red', show.legend = FALSE)  +
         scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c(ymd(date_last)-30,ymd(date_last)+1))) +
         scale_y_continuous(labels = comma, limits = c(0, NA)),
       tooltip = "text"
       
     ) %>%
       style (hoverlabel = list(font=list(size=20)))
     
     
   }
   )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
g1 <- ggplotly(ggplot(...) +
   geom_bar(...))

hide_legend(g1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to all, I just fixed the issue with `theme(legend.position = "none")`

Comment: not well described into where the theme should apply, consider always adding a more detailed code.